# Script Error on viewing report in Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer

Tags: windows

I installed a copy of **Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer 2.2** on my Windows XP (SP2) machine, using an administrator account connected to our domain.

Then I ran a scan on the machine itself to test it out, after it scanned successfully I wanted to open the report but this error pops up:

```
Internet Explorer Script Error
An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line: 156
Char: 11
Error: Object required
Code: 0
URL: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Baseline%20Security%20Analyzer%202/viewreport.html
Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
Yes No
```

Clicking on Yes or No makes no difference, the result is an empty page.

Other relevant information: I'm using **Internet Explorer 8**, and have the '*Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)*' and '*Disable script debugging (Other)*' checked.